# Hide Flask-Admin route

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-admin, flask-security

I'm building a Flask blog and setting up an admin interface now. I've read about setting up security for Flask-Admin. I've managed to set up security (access is restricted only to logged-in users) for all my models, but users can still access the '/admin' route which has just a bare home button in it.

My question is: is there any way I could hide or protect the '/admin' route, so an unauthenticated user is just redirected to the login page/ denied access?

Thanks a lot!

Attaching my current admin setup:

```
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_login import current_user
from flask_admin.contrib import sqla
from wtforms.widgets import TextArea
from wtforms import TextAreaField
from samo.models import User, Post, Tag
from samo import app,db

admin = Admin(app, name='Admin', template_mode='bootstrap3')

class CKTextAreaWidget(TextArea):
    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('class'):
            kwargs['class'] += ' ckeditor'
        else:
            kwargs.setdefault('class', 'ckeditor')
        return super(CKTextAreaWidget, self).__call__(field, **kwargs)      

class CKTextAreaField(TextAreaField):
    widget = CKTextAreaWidget()

class PostAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    form_overrides = dict(content=CKTextAreaField)
    create_template = 'blog/ckeditor.html'
    edit_template = 'blog/ckeditor.html'
    form_excluded_columns = ('slug')    
    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.is_authenticated
admin.add_view(PostAdmin(Post, db.session))

class TagAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.is_authenticated
admin.add_view(TagAdmin(Tag, db.session))

class UserAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.is_authenticated
admin.add_view(UserAdmin(User, db.session))
```

Comment: If you hide a route, how would you access it? Why can't you use redirect if not authenticated, like you said?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use such a configuration like you described it for all my Websites. Use an [AdminIndexView](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_base/?highlight=AdminIndexView). Here is an example of how  handle login, logout and redirection in case the user is not authorized.

```
class FlaskyAdminIndexView(AdminIndexView):

    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        if not login.current_user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect(url_for('.login'))
        return super(FlaskyAdminIndexView, self).index()

    @expose('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def login(self):
        form = LoginForm(request.form)
        if helpers.validate_form_on_submit(form):
            user = form.get_user()
            if user is not None and user.verify_password(form.password.data):
                login.login_user(user)
            else:
                flash('Invalid username or password.')
        if login.current_user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect(url_for('.index'))
        self._template_args['form'] = form
        return super(FlaskyAdminIndexView, self).index()

    @expose('/logout')
    @login_required
    def logout(self):
        login.logout_user()
        return redirect(url_for('.login'))
```

In your `__init__.py` where you create your admin object do this:

`admin = Admin(index_view=FlaskyAdminIndexView())`